# How to set generator to max value of column

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

How to set generator to max value of column in Firebird 2.5

I've tried this

```
ALTER  SEQUENCE GEN_ID_PROCESSO_ITEM RESTART WITH (SELECT max(id_processo_item) FROM LICITACAO_PROCESSO_ITEM )
```

---

```
SET GENERATOR GEN_ID_PROCESSO_ITEM TO (SELECT MAX(ID_processo_item ) + 1 FROM licitacao_processo_item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use select statement in DDL like `ALTER SEQUENCE` or `SET GENERATOR`. The fact that you want to do this is a bit suspect, as it means that you're using other means for generating ID values, where you should be using the sequence exclusively.

In any case, the only dynamic option is to use the [`GEN_ID` function](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-gen-id), which allows you to increment or decrement a sequence by arbitrary values, including `0`, which will only return the current value and not change the sequence. For example, if the current value of a sequence is `n` and the target value is `m`, then the desired increment is `m - n`:

```
select 
  gen_id(GEN_ID_PROCESSO_ITEM, 
    (select max(SELECT max(id_processo_item) - gen_id(GEN_ID_PROCESSO_ITEM, 0) 
     from LICITACAO_PROCESSO_ITEM)) 
from RDB$DATABASE
```

Example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k_dn_Pe2) (note, this uses Firebird 4, which has more options in `CREATE SEQUENCE` than Firebird 4, but the select statement used will also work on Firebird 2.5)

Other alternatives are:

1. Using an `EXECUTE BLOCK` to select the desired value, and then use `EXECUTE STATEMENT` to dynamically execute the DDL statement to change the sequence value
2. Writing a program or script in you favourite programming language to select the right value and then execute the DDL

However using `GEN_ID` is the most flexible option.